# Excel, Sumproduct, multiple conditions search in {}

Tags: excel

I run into several postings on the internet (incl. stackowerflow) with code like this

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A10="Marketing")*(B1:B10={"North","South"})*(C1:C10))
```

Conditions for search are neatly put into `{}`. I have 28 such conditions to search for, so I'm looking for a way to make the formula easier to read. If I try it, i get N/A.

Is there a trick I'm missing?

I'm aware that it can be written 
`(B1:B10="North") + (B1:B10="South")`
but with 28 items it is going to be long.

Thank you in advance

EDIT1: (Disregard)

Tried Axel's suggestion

Simple example

```
        -   A   B   C   D
        1       1   2   3
        2   1   2   2   3
        3   2   4   4   6
        4   3   6   6   9



 =SUMPRODUCT((A2:A4={2,3})*(B2:D4))

    Returns Sumproduct(({1,2,3}={2,3})*(B2:D4)) -> I still get N/A for last column when you continue in process

    Same for  
    =SUMPRODUCT((A2:A4=A6:B6)*(B2:D4))
    where A6:B6 is list of conditions

    or 

    =SUMPRODUCT((A2:A4=testrange)*(B2:D4))
```

I'm trying to put all conditions within formula `{"case1","case2",...}` and so but can't make it work.

Edit 2:
Ok, I see the difference now.
Initial formula is column by column by column

What I'm trying to solve

```
Column A- list of accounts, I need to find 28 of them 
Row 1 - months (conditions varies)
Range B2:AA462 - values
```

I can write it all with `(A2:A462="account1")+(A2:A462="acount2")...` up to 28 cases, but I'm asking whether there is a way to write it more simpler

Something like initial `A2:A462={"North","South"}`

Something like

```
=Sumproduct((A2:A462={"account1","account2",...})*(B1:AA1="June")*(B2:AA462))
```

Is there a way write this somehow?

EDIT 4:

Few weeks later inspired by Axel's inputs

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MMULT(--(A2:A7=G1:J1),ROW(1:4)/ROW(1:4))*(B1:E1=G4)*B2:E7)
```

Can be grown into

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(MMULT(--(A2:A7=TRANSPOSE(namedrange)),ROW(OFFSET(A1,0,0,COUNTA(namedrange)))/ROW(OFFSET(A1,0,0,COUNTA(namedrange))))*(B1:E1=G4)*(B2:E7))}
```

Ok, named range, has conditions within column, more natural way to keep a list of conditions you want to filter for. Also MMULT is now flexible, and counts number of conditions and adjust number of rows to multiply by. 
Whole formula must be entered as array formula.

Comment: Your "Simple example" is totally different from your original question since it uses a matrix `B2:D4` (3 rows, 3 columns) instead of vectors (either **one** row or **one** column). Please clarify what you are trying to achieve. What shall happen with the values in `B2:D4` if the criterias matches?

Comment: I see the difference now, EDIT 2 in initial post

Comment: Btw.: You are wrong.  `=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A4={2,3})*(B2:D4))` results in `SUMPRODUCT(({1;2;3}={2,3})*(B2:D4))` -> `SUMPRODUCT(({0,0;1,0;0,1})*(B2:D4))` (0=false, 1=true). So you have a matrix of 3 rows, 2 columns which shall be multipied wit a matrix of 3 rows, 3 columns. This is not possible. What shall be the result of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{"North","South"}` is the array literal for a row vector. That means it is as if "North" and "South" is placed in juxtaposed cells in one row. So if "North" is in `E1` and "South" is in `F1`, then the formula could also be:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A13="Marketing")*(B1:B13=E1:F1)*C1:C13)
```

With more criteria it could be:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A13="Marketing")*(B1:B13=E1:H1)*C1:C13)
```

It is important that the criterias are in a row vector (one row, multiple columns) since the `B1:B13` is a column vector.

---

Answer to your Edit 2:

The approach:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((A2:A462="account1")+(A2:A462="account2")+...+(A2:A462="account28"))*(B1:AA1="June")*B2:AA462)
```

, which will work, is different from `(A2:A462={"account1","account2",...,"account28"})`. The latter cannot work since it creates a matrix of 461 rows and 28 columns while the working one `((A2:A462="account1")+(A2:A462="account2")+...+(A2:A462="account28"))` is only a vector of 461 rows in one column.

The equivalent could be:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MMULT(--(A2:A462={"account1","account2",...,"account28"});ROW(1:28)/ROW(1:28))*(B1:AA1="June")*B2:AA462)
```

and if "account1","account2",...,"account28" are in `AC1:BD1` then also:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MMULT(--(A2:A462=AC1:BD1);ROW(1:28)/ROW(1:28))*(B1:AA1="June")*B2:AA462)
```

What is this doing? It uses `MMULT` to transform the matrix of 461 rows and 28 columns into a vector of 461 rows by multiplying the matrix with a row vector of 28 rows filled with 1.

So if there is a 1 in one of the 28 columns in each row of the matrix, then there will also be a 1 as the row value of the resulting vector of 461 rows.

Example:

[image]

Formula in `H3`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((A2:A7=G1)+(A2:A7=H1)+(A2:A7=I1)+(A2:A7=J1))*(B1:E1=G3)*B2:E7)
```

Formula in `H4`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MMULT(--(A2:A7=G1:J1),ROW(1:4)/ROW(1:4))*(B1:E1=G4)*B2:E7)
```

To be complete, there also would be an approach using `SUMIF` inside `SUMPRODUCT` which would be the better approach in my opinion.

So the Formula in `H4` would be:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(A2:A7,G1:J1,INDEX(B2:E7,0,MATCH(G5,B1:E1,0))))
```

Your formula would be:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(A2:A462,AC1:BD1,INDEX(B2:AA462,0,MATCH("June",B1:AA1,0))))
```